# Nginx - Forward All Request To Multiple Server - Multiport

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

how we can **forward all request to multiple servers with load balancing** like:

```
    upstream multiple {
        ip_hash;
        server A.A.A.A:1025-65535 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
        server B.B.B.B:1025-65535 weight=4 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
    }

    server {
        listen 1025-65535;
        proxy_pass multiple;
        }
```

I am new and I tried the following method but unfortunately it didn't work

```
    upstream multiple {
        ip_hash;
        server A.A.A.A:1025-65535 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
        server B.B.B.B:1025-65535 weight=4 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
    }

    server {
        listen 1025-65535;
        proxy_pass multiple;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thats not possible and not the purpose of nginx. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but might help others with the same problem.

You may want to checkout nginx ngx_http_mirror_module. Basically mirrors request by creating sub request going to your target server.

Here's a snippet from nginx website:

```
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

location = /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://test_backend$request_uri;
}
```